# sql server: recursive stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a very generic set of three tables that store all of my data, which works brilliantly (we are talking small quantities of data here)

**DataContainer - Manages 'records'**

```
PK - DataContainerId
FK - ParentDataContainerId
FM - ModelEntityId
```

**DataInstance - Manages versioning**

```
PK - DataInstanceId
FK - DataContainerId
     IsCurrent [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataInstance_IsCurrent]  DEFAULT ((1)),
     ModifiedBy [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataInstance_ModifiedBy]  DEFAULT (suser_sname()),
     ModifiedDateTime [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataInstance_ModifiedDateTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
```

**DataValue**

```
PK - DataValueId
FK - DataInstanceId
FK - ModelEntityId
     ValueText --the actual values
```

Problem: When a record is deleted I need to flag all child records for deletion.

**Attempt**

```
--flag current record as deleted
update DataInstance 
set IsCurrent = 0
Where DataContainerId = @DataContainerId
And (@ModelContainerId is null or @ModelContainerId = ModelContainerId)

--remove all child records
declare db_cursor for
select sc.DataContainerId as 'ChildDataContainerId' from DataInstance di
inner join datacontainer dc on dc.datacontainerId = di.datacontainerId
where parentdatacontainerId = @DataContainerId

declare @ChildDataContainerId int
open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @ChildDataContainerId

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  exec dataInstance_Delete null, @ChildDataContainerId --current sp
end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

The problem is that I cant use cursors recursivly (as I get an error that the cursor is already open), so this SP will only work one level deep.

Is there a more cunning way to do this?

Comment: Storing all of your data in one table and then using cursors to process your records are practices that you should get away from.  You're asking for a headache when you're ignoring the wisdom of normalizing your data and the power of set logic that SQL was designed for...  Maybe you should consider refactoring for your own benefit later on?

Comment: Since I hate sticks in the mud that just post negative remarks and then walk away here's one solution to your issue if you decide to plow forward: use an application programming language outside of SQL to do the recursion.  They are usually not restricted by recursive call rules and you can process records more easily with a recordset or equivalent if you prefer row logic.  Happy coding...

Comment: I have to agree with Tahbaza but if you insist on taking this route, I would use a trigger. Triggers can be executed recursively (up to a certain (configurable I believe) level).

Comment: Could you explain the structure of your table. Your post says that your only have one table, but when I look at the stored procedure that you have listed it looks like you are referencing two tables, a table called DataInstance and a table called datacontainer.

Comment: I do not use cursors anywhere else (use set logic), essentially I have a OO database design in a relational database.  I do want the referential integrity on all of my metadata, but for the data itself, obviously there is very little. This means I can use one schema for every application I develop.. it has worked extremely well. Possibly a NoSql option, or XML would have fitted quite nicely, but I do like databases in general.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I usually dumb down my eplanation for users, which I should not have done here ;)

There are Actually 3 - have modified my description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tahbaza suggested, it was a fairly simple trigger,

```
create trigger DataInstance_Trigger
    On DataInstance
After update
as
Begin
    Update
        DataInstance
    Set
        DataInstance.IsCurrent = 0
    From DataInstance di, Inserted i
    Inner join DataContainer dc on
       i.DataContainerId = dc.ParentDataContainerId
    Where di.DataContainerId = dc.DataContainerId
          di.IsCurrent = 1
```

End